# expected ‘float *’ but argument is of type ‘float’ and incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘find_m’

Tags: c

I'm trying to write least square method in C.

```
cc least_square.c -lm -o least_square
```

i get this error after compile it with gcc.

```
least_square.c: In function ‘main’:
least_square.c:37:32: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘find_m’
           printf("m = %.3f\n", find_m(x[i], x[i], k)) ; 
                                ^
least_square.c:8:11: note: expected ‘float *’ but argument is of type ‘float’
     float find_m(float [], float [], int data_number) ;
           ^
least_square.c:37:32: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘find_m’
           printf("m = %.3f\n", find_m(x[i], x[i], k)) ; 
                                ^
least_square.c:8:11: note: expected ‘float *’ but argument is of type ‘float’
     float find_m(float [], float [], int data_number) ;
           ^
least_square.c:38:32: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘find_n’
           printf("n = %.3f\n", find_n(x[i], y[i], k)) ; 
                                ^
least_square.c:10:11: note: expected ‘float *’ but argument is of type ‘float’
     float find_n(float [], float [], int data_number) ;
           ^
least_square.c:38:32: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘find_n’
           printf("n = %.3f\n", find_n(x[i], y[i], k)) ; 
                                ^
least_square.c:10:11: note: expected ‘float *’ but argument is of type ‘float’
     float find_n(float [], float [], int data_number) ;
```

My codes :
    /* y = mx + n  --- Using least square method */

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>


    float find_m(float [], float [], int data_number) ;

    float find_n(float [], float [], int data_number) ;


    int main(){


       int k, i ;    

       printf("Number of data(k)\n? ") ;
       scanf("%d", &k) ;

       float x[k] ;    
       float y[k] ;

       for (i = 0 ; i <= (k - 1) ; i++){    
          x[i] = 0 ;
          y[i] = 0 ; 
       } 

       for (i = 0 ; i <= (k - 1) ; i++){

          printf("%d. point x coordinate(xi)\n? ", i+1) ;  /* get data */
          scanf("%f", &x[i]) ;

          printf("%d. point y coordinate(yi)\n? ", i+1) ;
          scanf("%f", &y[i]) ;

          printf("m = %.3f\n", find_m(x[i], x[i], k)) ; 
          printf("n = %.3f\n", find_n(x[i], y[i], k)) ; 
       }


       return 0 ;       


    }


    float find_m(float x[], float y[], int data_number){   /* Find constant m */


       int i,
           a = 0, 
           b = 0, 
           c = 0,
           d = 0,
           e = 0 ; 

       for (i = 0 ; i <= (data_number - 1) ; i++){

          a += x[i] * y[i] ;

          b += x[i] ;

          c += y[i] ;

          d += pow(x[i], 2) ;

          e += x[i] ; 
       }   


       return ((data_number * a) - (b * c)) / ((data_number * d) - pow(e, 2)) ;


    }


    float find_n(float x[], float y[], int data_number){        /*Find constant n*/


       int i,
           a = 0, 
           b = 0, 
           c = 0,
           d = 0,
           e = 0,
           f = 0;
       float n ; 

       for (i = 0 ; i <= (data_number - 1) ; i++){

          a += pow(x[i], 2) ;

          b += y[i] ;

          c += x[i] * y[i] ;

          d += x[i] ;

          e += pow(x[i], 2) ;

          f += x[i] ; 
       }   


       return (((a * b) - (c * d)) / ((data_number * e) - pow(f, 2))) ;


    }
```

I couldn't make out what my mistakes are. I think everything is right.

Error says "expected float *" but i have already made argument type float.

Comment: "_Error says "expected float *" but i have already made argument type float._" -- `float*` and `float` are different. The former is a pointer to a `float` while the latter is just a `float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `find_m` and `find_n` have pointers to float as first two parameters. Their signatures are equivalent to this:

```
float find_m(float*, float*, int data_number) ;

float find_n(float*, float*, int data_number) ;
```

You are passing `float`s as arguments. You need to pass pointers. Without fully understanding the purpose of your code, it is difficult to provide a real, working solution. A possibility is that you want to scan part of the arrays in each iteration, in which case, you can use the array names as arguments. These will decay to pointers to the first elements of the arrays.

```
printf("m = %.3f\n", find_m(x, x, k)) ; 
printf("n = %.3f\n", find_n(x, y, k)) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find_m(x[i], x[i], k)
```

This is wrong, because, `x[i]` is a `float` whereas `find_m` takes `float *` as first and second parameter. Try this:

```
find_m(x, x, k)
```

and

```
find_m(x, y, k)
```

inside your `printf`:

```
printf("m = %.3f\n", find_m(x, x, k)) ; 
printf("n = %.3f\n", find_n(x, y, k)) ;
```

Look, in function calls `find_m` the name of the array, `x` and `y`, as an argument, is an expression evaluates to a pointer to the array. In other words, the expression, `x` and `y`, is a pointer to (the first element of) the array, `x[]` and `y[]`. Its type is, therefore, float *, and a called function uses this pointer (passed as an argument) to indirectly access the elements of the array.

Answer (score -2):

Among other things here are a few problems with the code at first glance:

```
int k, i;

printf("Number of data(k)\n? ");
scanf("%d", &k);

float x[k];
float y[k];
```

You can't create arrays in this manner, arrays are not created on variable sizes given by the user. If you want variable sizes entered by the user you will need to use dynamic allocation - for more information check here: http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation

Next -  you received errors due to `find_m(x[i], x[i], k)` since you pass in two arrays that are suppose to hold data values x and y. However you are passing two `float *` pointers to arrays, if you need more material on this information you can look here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_pointers_to_functions.htm

The functions should be declared as `float find_m(float*, float*, int data_number);` instead of the later. Please debug your program and step through each function to see how data is being passed, it will help in the end.

Comment: Thank you. I'm beginner programmer and ı didn't know that dynamic allocation. Thanks to you, i learned that and used in my program. Thanks again :)

Comment: @KutayArinc - just glad I could be of some help!